# Broadcast Intent and IntentFilter in android

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, android-broadcast

I'm trying to broadcast Intent between 2 activities.

The Intent is sent from FilterActivity to PreviewActivity as shown below

```
final Intent ImageIntent = new Intent();
ImageIntent.setData(uri);
ImageIntent.setAction("com.test.FILTER_RENDERED");
sendBroadcast(ImageIntent);
```

In the PreviewActivity I need to register the receiver and use an IntentFiter to catch the Intent and check it.

```
public class PreviewActivity extends Activity {

    ReceiveMessages myReceiver = null;
    Boolean myReceiverIsRegistered = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        myReceiver = new ReceiveMessages();
        if (!myReceiverIsRegistered) {
            // registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter());
            registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.test.FILTER_RENDERED"));

            myReceiverIsRegistered = true;
        }
     ....

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if (!myReceiverIsRegistered) {
            registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.test.FILTER_RENDERED"));
            myReceiverIsRegistered = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (myReceiverIsRegistered) {
            unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
            myReceiverIsRegistered = false;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Intent mNewIntent = intent;

        Bundle bundle = null;
        String fragment = null;
        if (intent != null) {
            mImagePreviewUri = mNewIntent.getData();
            if(mImagePreviewUri!=null) {
                mCameraActionsView.setEnabled(true);
                mImagePreview.setImageURI(mImagePreviewUri);
            }
        }
    }

    public class ReceiveMessages extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            String action = intent.getAction();
             if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("com.test.FILTER_RENDERED")){
                if (intent != null) {
                    mImagePreviewUri = intent.getData();
                    if(mImagePreviewUri!=null) {
                        mCameraActionsView.setEnabled(true);
                        mImagePreview.setImageURI(mImagePreviewUri);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, the Intent is never received by the activity<

Any idea why, OnReceive is not triggered ?

Answer (score 1):

The parameter is the `IntentFilter` constructor is for the **action**. So you should use the same string as in the `setAction` method of your intent.

The best way to do so, whiout doing mistake (like typo) is to define a constant somewhere (let say it is in Constant class) :

```
public static final String YOUR_ACTION = "whaterver_you_want";
```

Then use this constant. When you build your intent :

```
intent.setAction(Constant.YOUR_ACTION);
```

And when you build your filter :

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Constant.YOUR_ACTION);
```